# grep to sed, append after string match but instead on end of line

Tags: bash, sed

I have the following text file with the following lines:

```
<test="123">
<test="456">
<test="789">
```

My aim is to have the above text file to be appended with a keyword "HELLO" after the above numbers, as following:

```
  <test="123.HELLO">
  <test="456.HELLO">
  <test="789.HELLO">
```

with the grep command and cut, I manage to get the value between the quotation mark.

```
grep -o "test=".* test.txt | cut -d \" -f2
```

I tried to use sed on top of it, with this line

```
grep -o "test=".* test.txt | cut -d \" -f2 | sed -i -- 's/$/.HELLO/' test.txt
```

however the closest I manage to get is instead a ".HELLO" which directly appended on the end of the line (and not after the numbers in between the quotes)

```
<test="123">.HELLO 
<test="456">.HELLO 
<test="789">.HELLO
```

How can I fix my sed statement to provide me with the requested line?

Comment: can you clarify: 1) spaces in front of expected output lines is needed or falsely shown here because of formatting 2) does your input file contain lines not containing `test=`? if so, should they be part of output as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with groups in sed. To create new output, you can do this:

```
 sed 's/\(test="[^"]*\)"/\1.HELLO"/g' test.txt
```

To modify it in-place, you can use the `-i` switch:

```
 sed -i 's/\(test="[^"]*\)"/\1.HELLO"/g' test.txt
```

Explanation:

- `()` is a group. You can refer to it with `\1`. In sed we have to escape the parentheses: `\(\)`
- `[^"]*` matches everything that's not a quote. So the match will stop before the quote
- In the replacement, you have to add the quote manually, since it's outside of the group. So you can put stuff before the quote.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with sed directly. Cut should not be necessary:

```
grep "test=" test.txt | sed 's/"\(.*\)"/"\1.HELLO"/'
```

Comment: grep is unnecessary too, as well as `-o` option should not be used in this case.. and you could add some sample filename to grep command...

Comment: Good call, edited my answer. I left the grep in, in case there are extraneous lines in the file that the OA wants left out. Of course it could be done with sed directly, but this seems more simplistic.

Comment: fine now :) `sed -n '/test=/ s/"\(.*\)"/"\1.HELLO"/p' test.txt` is simple too, but I do get your point :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

This is how your file looks like.

```
bash > cat a.txt
<test="123">
<test="456">
<test="789">
```

Your text piped to SED

```
bash > cat a.txt |sed 's/">/.HELLO">/g'
<test="123.HELLO">
<test="456.HELLO">
<test="789.HELLO">
bash >
```

Let me know if this worked out for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'sub("[0-9]+","&.HELLO")' file
```